# Jenkins: Should I use different local maven repositories for my builds?

Tags: maven, jenkins, continuous-integration

I have a Jenkins instance running builds of multiple microservices and libraries.

Currently, I have my build configured in a way that all the jobs use different local repository locations `$WORKSPACE/.m2/repository`.

This is good because the builds have no way of influencing each other, however, builds obviously tend to be a lot longer, because they need to download all the dependencies every single time.

What do you think is the better solution? Shall I keep the current configuration, or is it safe enough to use the same local repo location for all the jobs?

Is there a way to ensure that builds can't influence each other, even though the local repo is the same?

What comes to my mind is I could configure the project so that all SNAPSHOTs are updated every time. Is this enough? How can I do it from my `settings.xml`?

---

I got some questions in comments and I think answering them here is better, so:

> Why do I delete my repository folder before each build?

Because the repo is in the jenkins job folder (currently). I clean the job folder, because I sometimes need to modify the pom during build. (Change version for a release).

> Do you have many branches? Do you use a repository manager?

Yes, I do.

> How many jenkins nodes do you have?

Currently only one, but this might change in the future.

> How do you build on Jenkins (meaning) which exact maven execution command do you use in Jenkins?

I use `mvn clean deploy`, with some additional properties

Comment: Do you delete the `.repository` before/after each build?

Comment: yes, I do a clean start each time. Maybe this is another direction I can enhance performance

Comment: Why do you do so? How do you build on Jenkins (meaning) which exact maven execution command do you use in Jenkins? Do you have many branches? The other thing is: Do you use a repository manager? How many jenkins nodes do you have?

Comment: I answered your questions in an edit

Comment: Based on that situation I would only use a repository located to each workspace in Jenkins. But I wouldn't delete that space for each build before/after the build. Furthermore I would like to know how much time your build takes? How many module/tests/ etc. you have?

Comment: Currently, not a lot. I just implemented a new Jenkins pipeline, so I don't know 100% what my build times are. They are in the 2-5min mark, with (currently) few tests and few modules. These will increase a lot though

Comment: I can recommend to observe those informations over the time ... which means how many tests you have and how long the tests take... if you have a number of modules (ca. 10+) you can start to run your build in parallel via Maven.. I have several build ca. 4000 unit tests / 40 modules/ 40k lines of code etc. 4:30 Minutes to build...ca. 1.5 minutes for the unit tests... also had a very large build 800 modules/2.5 million lines of code/25k tests/ build ca. 15 minutes. Also check the performance of the machines you have ... SSD hard drives etc. IO is vital...

Comment: ohh yeah, these modules are not in one maven project. These are in different git repositories and all, as opposed to one fat project

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you do, make sure that one local repository is not used by more than one build at a time. The local repository is not safe for concurrent use. You easily break the metadata if two builds try to update the same SNAPSHOT.

Answer (score 0):

My current solution is that I made a directory outside of jenkins home, `/maven/.m2/repository/`. But this is not the local repository itself.

The actual repository is: `<localRepository>/maven/.m2/repository/${env.JOB_NAME}</localRepository>`. This way, I get a different repo for every job, but it doesn't get deleted when the workspace gets deleted for the job.